# The name given to the trail of afterburn (of a jet perhaps?)

Tags: british-english

What is the name of the trail (of after burn) left by a jet?

I know it's something nearly like "after burn", but I can't be sure as I've not used it for quite a long time!

Comment: What do you mean by "after burn"? As far as I know, only jets use afterburners, so what do you mean by "by a jet *perhaps*?

Comment: @Jim, and not all jets at that, an addition to a limited set of jet engines where performance is more important than efficiency. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterburner

Comment: You should also look in aviation.stackexchange.com to see if it's been discussed there (and to ask if you are able to).

Answer (score 22):

[image: Contrails from a four-engine fixed wing aircraft]

If you are referring to the cirrus-cloud-like vapor trails left by jets, the name for those is *[contrails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrail)* (short for condensation trails), *vapor trails*, or even *cirrus aviaticus*.

**Edited to add**: *Chemtrails* is an 'allegation' more than a fact. I include it here because it is still unclear what OP wants a *name* for. Since he included *after burn*, I thought he might be referring to fuel residue. While I think *contrails* is what he's after, I also recognize that fuel does not burn with 100% efficiency, so there actually exist pollutants in (and around) contrails; I have no idea how quickly the pollutants diffuse out of the moisture-laden contrail. But I am no believer in chemtrails as the term is used by… other folks.

**Also** *wingtip vortices* are usually invisible; they may become visible under certain unusual conditions unlikely to be encountered from large aircraft, so it is unlikely OP is looking for that as an answer.

Comment: Careful with the word *chemtrails*. It's popular in certain... Less than fully rational circles.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - agreed, but they are not simply condensed water vapor. There are some organic chemicals in them. But they don't cause snow to burn or other bats**t claims.

Comment: Chemtrails today feed the crop circles of tomorrow.

Comment: _How much flying_ do you do?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - you mean, myself, without aircraft? None. With aircraft, a fair bit. Why? (I'm dense)

Comment: Nothing cryptic – just that giving five answers shows a fair degree of expertise. Speaking planely.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - ah. I read a lot about them once in an effort to prove a picture was shopped, when no one else believed me (it was, of course).

Comment: They ought to get your opinion on the Malaysian jet mystery.

Comment: What have constrails got to do with afterburners? They are simply precipitate moisture left as the by product of combustion.

Comment: @Jodrell, the OP mentioned "trails", which afterburners do not leave, so I think this answer might be what they're looking for. Susan: the answer is "contrail", not "chemtrail". They've been called contrails since the 1950's and none of the other answers come close. They are not caused by wing tip vortices or chemicals.

Comment: @Wayne, the combustion of any hydrogen containing fuel is likely to produce water and therefore condensation. Con(densation)trails can also be caused by disturbances in air pressure caused by wing tips. Afterburners do nothing to counteract this effect indeed, I assert burning more fuel yields more water. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrail

Comment: @susan - a wingtip vortex is an entirely different thing than a contrail, and is invisible to the eye.  It extends off the tip of the wing and can cause a small plane serious trouble if they hit one unexpectedly

Comment: @Susan: not disagreeing on the afterburners thing. A wingtip vortex can be visible under extreme conditions (like a fighter jet doing crazy maneuvers), but I think "contrail" is the far-and-away best of your proposed answers -- given that we're understanding the OP's question.

Comment: @Oldcat, Wayne - I don't doubt you, but I was given to understand that under certain conditions, the pressure differential in wingtip vortices causes moisture to condense - something like cavitation underwater - and so becomes visible. If I'm mistaken, I'll remove it from my answer.

Comment: I suppose that could happen, or if the vortex ran into something visible and disturbed it you could see its effects.  But much of the danger of a vortex is that you **don't** see them and they can have effects after the plane is long passed the area.

Comment: @Oldcat - Thank you, I remember now that an occasional airplane accident is blamed on one plane encountering another's vortex. I'll edit.

Answer (score 8):

If you are specifically referring to an afterburner (where fuel is injected directly into the jet exhaust to generate extra thrust) there is a characteristic pattern of flames fronts produced called [shock diamonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_diamonds) ( or sometimes dancing diamonds )

[image]

Comment: Wow! +1 - is this done routinely in flight? It looks like something done in space travel.

Comment: Not "routine", but it is done (mostly fighter jets needing a burst of acceleration)

Comment: Not if they can help it - it's incredibly inefficient on fuel. But IIRC only Concorde could do Mach2 WITHOUT afterburner - all military jets need it for top speed. The SR71 needed it all the time, even for takeoff

Comment: @Susan, jet engines work by heating air to increase pressure. This is why they have a limited speed and altitude. When there is not enough air, they don't work. For space you need something else, like a rocket.

Comment: @Jodrell - actually they compress (pressurize) the air in the intake which heats it, then mix it with fuel and burn it, which also heats it.

Answer (score 3):

You might be referring to **jet wash**, which the heated air coming out of a jet engine when the jet accelerates on take off.

Here is a video ([Temora sabre take off with jet wash, crazy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SgYLSAjqgw)) of that happening, taken by what appear to be group of British aviation enthusiasts. I mention this because you specifically tagged this for British English. (Starts at the 1:00 mark, if you want to jumpy right to it.

Here is another example, with the caption "Look at that jet wash"
[image]

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_wash), it defined as:

> Wake turbulence, turbulence that forms behind an aircraft as it passes through the air

*Jet wash* is also a common term for a car wash, apparently using high pressure nozzles. So I thought this picture might be of interest:

[image]

I prefer to use a hand wash.

Comment: What is the source for that last picture?

Comment: [Here](http://cars.uk.msn.com/features/top-gear/the-greatest-top-gear-moments?page=9) I hadn't looked at the page until now, and thought it might be photoshopped. But the guys on the British car show *Top Gear* are wild. This has to be real. (This came from google.co.uk searching for *jet wash*.)

Comment: I don't believe that the heated air comes out of a jet *engineer*.

Comment: Oops! Noted. My fingers don't always obey when I type.

Comment: I think this answer confuses three separate concepts.    Wake turbulence is composed not only of the direct thrust from the engines - the jet wash - but more significantly the wash from the wings.  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Airplane_vortex_edit.jpg  http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_M9fxO-cJats/THPJPpYPmOI/AAAAAAAAAuc/Nht05QmnD2Q/s1600/Vortices.jpg  It's not usually thought of as a "trail". and is separate from the contrail, which is purely exhaust-caused.   Its definitely hard to tell if the OP is asking about contrails, jet wash or wake turbulence.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that this question may be referring to

1) Contrails, as described by @Susan

[image]

This is the closest thing to the description in the question: a **trail**  containing "after burn" IE exhaust products

2) Jet Wash, as described by @Jim

[image]

This is not a trail, in the sense of something that lies around after the plan has passed.   It doesn't actually extend very far back behind the aircraft

3) Wake Turbulence

[image]

(Note that this is *not* coming from the propellor, the vortex comes from the tip of the wing)

[image]

This *is* a trail, it does extend far behind the plane, and causes trouble for other aircraft behind it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yfb_usoubg

However, it is not comprised (primarily) of engine exhaust products (afterburn), and is not usually visible.

4) After-burn from an Afterburner, as described by @mgb

[image]

This is a special case of Jet Wash - it is jet wash from an Afterburner - a special engine feature.

I suspect that this is not actually what the OP is asking about - the sentence the OP used (and possibly not English as a first language?) appears to mean "exhaust" by the phrase "of afterburn".

Comment: So, you read the other answers ...

Comment: Yes, I read the other answers, and found that there was some synthesis and extra information (about wake turbulence in particular) to be added, and made some connections between all of them and the original question.

Comment: the trail is obviously generated by the exhaust. I hoped to be more specific so avoided the obvious to facilitate room for thought. English is the only language I know despite my native language being Tamil- the extraterrestrial language passed down to Earth through India 0.03 million years ago. surprisingly, evidence has also appeared on the "web" but through western scholars